# Move PHP echo to another div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a website with div1 and div2. div1 contains a button which triggers an ajax function that connects to a PHP file which gets some content from the database. The database then echo's out some output. The problem is that this output gets shown in the same div as the button is in. I need it to be shown in div2 and not div1.

I have heard this can be acomplished using JQuery since it can move some echo'ed code form one div to another, but I can't find anything that relates to my problem. Maybe you know it.

Here is some code that might help understanding the problem:

```
<div id="house_wall1"> //This is the div2
 <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true): ?>
    <?php
        require('database/refresh_house.php');

        //This is the place I want the element echo'ed out.
    ?>
</div>
```

Here is the database call, which is called using ajax.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT x, y, z, src, rotation, link, div_id FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE house_room1.ref_id = ?')) {

        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_number);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $z, $src, $rotation, $link, $div_id);


        $data = '';
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($link != "") {
        $data.='<a href="' . $link . '"> ';
    }
    if ($div_id != "") {
        $data.= '<a href="#" onClick="' . $div_id . '"> ';
    }
        $data.= '<img src="' . $src . $rotation .'.png" class="item' . $item_number . '" style="position:absolute; left:' . $x . 'px; top:' . $y . 'px; z-index:'. $z . ';">'; if ($x != 0) { echo'</a>'; }


}



     } else {
        echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

As you can see, it echos out something in a while loop, this while loop echo's it out in the wrong div and I need that to be displayed in div2. I don't think using `include` would be a possibility since the code has to be a part of the Ajax function. And since Ajax is asyncronous, it has to be there.

Uhm any ideas, advice or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Ajax code:

```
function rotateObject(e)
{
    //e is handler which contains info about the item clicked. From that we can obtain the image id.
    //since the id are of the form img_123(some number), we need to extract only the number.
    var img_id = e.id.split("_")[1];
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("item-2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","database/update_settings_rotate.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("item_id="+encodeURIComponent(img_id));
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide your AJAX code? That's where the change will need to be made.

Comment: thanks @Jon , I have now added that Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key line:

```
document.getElementById("item-2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

You need to specify the element ID for the div2 if you want the response to your AJAX request to be displayed in that div.

Comment: Wow really? This sounds easier than I thought, what do I do to specify that? Thanks!

Comment: Well, instead of having "item-2" you need to have "div2" or whatever the ID attribute of your target div is...

Comment: Just write "house_wall1" instead of "item-2"?

Comment: Oh nice, only problem now is that I get an sql error, but I guess that's beyond the scope of this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, glad you sorted it. In the future, please read up on the Javascript that you are using... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Answer (score 1):

To move the content from DIV1 to DIV2 with jQuery:

```
var content = $('#DIV1').html();
$('#DIV2').html(content);
// if needed, clean the other div content
$('#DIV1').html('')
```

You can add this functionality to the "complete" function of the AJAX Call, that will be called when the request finishes.

Here you have an example:

```
$.ajax({
url:        url,
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        // code to execute before request
},
success: function(data, textStatus, error) {
        // code to execute when request succeeds
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        // code to execute before request fails
},
complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        // HERE WRITE YOUR CODE
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this as well, I am open for all ideas